# replace all vowels in a string javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will remove all vowels in a given string in JS. I understand that I can just write string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi,"") but I am trying to complete it a different way...this is what I have so far... thank you!

I first made a different function called IsaVowel that will return the character if it is a vowel...

```
function withoutVowels(string) {

var withoutVowels = "";
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (isaVowel(string[i])) {
 ***not sure what to put here to remove vowels***
       }
  }
    return withoutVowels;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to do anything there, you want to do something in the `else` clause.

Comment: Mark answer if problem is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Use accumulator pattern.

```js
function withoutVowels(string) {

  var withoutVowels = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      if (!isVowel(string[i])) {
        withoutVowels += string[i];
      }
    }
    return withoutVowels;
}

function isVowel(char) {
  return 'aeiou'.includes(char);
}

console.log(withoutVowels('Hello World!'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this problem by first splitting the string into an array, while also creating an array of vowels. Then go through each element in the string array and check whether it's in my vowel array. If it is not in my vowel array, push it to the withoutVowels array. At the end of the for loop, join all elements in the withoutvowels array and return.

```
function withoutVowels(string) {
            var strWithoutVowels =  [];
            string = string.split('');
            var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                if (vowels.indexOf(string[i]) < 0) {
                    strWithoutVowels.push(string[i])
                }
            }
            strWithoutVowels = strWithoutVowels.join('');
            return strWithoutVowels;
        }
        console.log(withoutVowels('Hello World!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use a regex; it's cleaner and faster compared to all your loops. Below is the code.

```js
string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');
```

the gi in the code means no matter the case whether uppercase or lowercase so long as its a vowel, it will be removed